# How to set Button.Command from a ResourceDictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to implement a hamburger button by myself in a Windows 10 app. I'm running into a little trouble with my `ResourceDictionary` when trying to set the `Command` property of a `Button` (via a style). Here is my code:

**Hamburger.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="Octopie.Styles.Hamburger"
    xmlns:local="using:Octopie.Styles">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Square.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style x:Key="HamburgerStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding OnClicked}"/> <!--This is the part that's having issues-->
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE700;"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Hamburger.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Octopie.Styles
{
    public sealed partial class Hamburger : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public Hamburger()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ICommand OnClicked => new ClickedCommand();

        private class ClickedCommand : ICommand
        {
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

            public bool CanExecute(object parameter) =>
                parameter is Button;

            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                var button = (Button)parameter;

                // Walk up the tree until we reach a SplitView
                FrameworkElement parent = button;
                do
                    parent = parent.Parent as FrameworkElement;
                while (!(parent is SplitView));

                var splitView = (SplitView)parent;
                splitView.IsPaneOpen = !splitView.IsPaneOpen;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the binding for the `Command` property doesn't seem to be working; when I set a breakpoint inside the `Execute` method and click the button, the breakpoint is never hit. I tried adding a `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` to the top of the XAML file, but for some reason `ResourceDictionary` doesn't seem to support `DataContext`.

**tl;dr:** What can I do to make the `Button.Command` property bind correctly to `OnClicked` within the setter?

Comment: How is this releated to [tag:windows-10] - rather to [tag:uwp], isn't it?

Comment: If the Command is part of your bound data, then it won't make sense to do what you are doing now. But if the Command is separate, then you can define your command like <local:MyCustomCommand x:Key="CmdKey"/> in res. dic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Mike said, usually we won't set `Button.Command` in `ResourceDictionary`. A hamburger button may not only be in `SplitView` but can be in another place and then you may need bind another command. So you can refer to Mike's suggestion.

But if you do want to set it in `ResourceDictionary`, you can try like following:

Firstly, in your case, your command is fixed, you can declare your `ClickedCommand` as a `public class`, then in the `Style`,set the `Command` like:

```
<Setter Property="Command">
    <Setter.Value>
        <local:ClickedCommand />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

After this, you can use your command, but this won't fix your problem as in `ClickedCommand`, you use `parameter` to retrieve the `Button`, but the `parameter` is not the "sender" of the `Command`, but the `object` passed with `CommandParameter` property. So we need set this in the `Style`.

However, Bindings in Style Setters are not supported in UWP Apps. See **Remarks** in [Setter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.setter):

> The Windows Runtime doesn't support a **Binding** usage for **Setter.Value** (the **Binding** won't evaluate and the **Setter** has no effect, you won't get errors, but you won't get the desired result either).

A workaround for this is using [attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185581.aspx) to set up the binding in code behind for you. For example:

```
public class BindingHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterBindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "CommandParameterBinding", typeof(bool), typeof(BindingHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, CommandParameterBindingPropertyChanged));

    public static bool GetCommandParameterBinding(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(CommandParameterBindingProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommandParameterBinding(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CommandParameterBindingProperty, value);
    }

    private static void CommandParameterBindingPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(d, Button.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding { RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { Mode = RelativeSourceMode.Self } });
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `Style`, using

```
<Setter Property="local:BindingHelper.CommandParameterBinding" Value="True" />
```

will set the `Button` as `CommandParameter`. Your Hamburger.xaml may like:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Octopie.Styles">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Square.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style x:Key="HamburgerStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Command">
            <Setter.Value>
                <local:ClickedCommand />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="local:BindingHelper.CommandParameterBinding" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE700;" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I delete `x:Class="Octopie.Styles.Hamburger"` and Hamburger.xaml.cs as there is no need to use code-behind for your `ResourceDictionary`.

Now we can use this `ResourceDictionary` in our page like:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Hamburger.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <SplitView DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="True">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource HamburgerStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

But there is another problem in `Execute` method of `ClickedCommand`. In this method, you've used [`FrameworkElement.Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.parent.aspx) to retrieve the `SplitView`. But

> **Parent** can be null if an object was instantiated, but is not
>   attached to an object that eventually connects to a page object root.
>
> Most of the time, **Parent** is the same value as returned by
>   [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) APIs. However, there may be cases where **Parent**
>   reports a different parent than **VisualTreeHelper** does.

And in your case, you need use `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` to get the `SplitView`. We can use a helper method to do this:

```
public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
    //get parent item
    DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    //we've reached the end of the tree
    if (parentObject == null) return null;

    //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
    T parent = parentObject as T;
    if (parent != null)
        return parent;
    else
        return FindParent<T>(parentObject);
}
```

Then in `Execute` method using:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var button = (Button)parameter;
    var splitView = FindParent<SplitView>(button);
    splitView.IsPaneOpen = !splitView.IsPaneOpen;
}
```

Now the `HamburgerStyle` will work as you want.

Comment: Your answer states _in your case, your command is fixed, you can declare (...) in `Style`_, so I'd like to ask: how do I modify it so that a commonly named `ClickedCommand`, implemented **differently in each `ViewModel`**, can be set via this common `Style`?

Answer (score 2):

What the hell?

You're going about this all wrong. You **don't need** to declare a new `ICommand` in a `ResourceDictionary`, it simply **doesn't belong there**. It belongs in your `View Model`, or whatever the `Button.DataContext` is set to.

The purpose of a `Style` is to control the look and feel of your controls, they should not explicitly set their own behaviours (commands).

Let me show you an example. You should declare your button like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource HamburgerStyle}" Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}"/>
```

*Where `ClickedCommand` is an object in your `View Model`.*

Your `HamburgerStyle` should **not** set it's own `Command` property, otherwise you are limiting your `Button` to one **single implementation** of `ICommand`, this is unwise.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean I have to write the same boilerplate every time I want to implement a hamburger button? For example, in the code-behind I would have to write `private void OnButtonClicked() { SplitView.IsPaneOpen = !SplitView.IsPaneOpen }`.

Comment: It sounds to me like this would probably make more sense if it was a `UserControl` instead of a `Style`.